# how to draw Rectangle block using tikzpicture in negative direction?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an image file that has 3 columns, I want to draw blocks around it, I tried the following code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\unitlength=1mm
\begin{picture}(170,150)


\put(-43,141){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\put(-38,160){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{1a}}
\put(22,160){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{1a}}
\put(-38,120){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{1a}}
\put(22,120){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{1a}}
\put(-38,92){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{1a}}
\put(22,92){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{1a}}
\put(-45,25){\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{1a}}
\put(25,25){\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{1a}}
\put(95,25){\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{1a}}

\end{picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can find the figure here.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ri61srUxsrTXnRUFIDqlf1l30J4z8tqU/view?usp=sharing

The problem is that I am getting only half of the image covered and when I tried to make (0,0) with negative values but it does not make sense

Comment: to draw the same rectangle `\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,8);`

Comment: Thanks, but I want to take my origin in the negative side, if I am doing that I am not getting the required answer.

Comment: I don't understand where your image comes into this, can you make a complete example?

Comment: You can use `example-image` instead of `1a`, that is an image which basically everyone has easily available, as it's included with TeX Live/MikTeX. It's perhaps a bit odd to put a `tikzpicture` in a `\put` like that, but if the frame drawn by the `tikzpicture` is in the wrong place, you need to change the coordinates of the `\put` I think.

Comment: I would either do the whole thing using picture or tikzpicture and not try to mix the two.

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.3\linewidth}
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \centering
\includegraphics{1a}\hfil
\includegraphics{1a}

\medskip
\includegraphics{1a}\hfil
\includegraphics{1a}

\medskip
\includegraphics{1a}\hfil
\includegraphics{1a}

\medskip
\includegraphics{1a}\hfil
\includegraphics{1a}\hfil
\includegraphics{1a}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
` ?